# Multiple SetState on async data fetching data from Firestore causing performance-hampering blinking effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, rerender

I'm experiencing an issue with React and FireBase.
I'm working on a basic website framework front-end project.
There's a central `App` JS file that hosts a `Router`, which contains a `Header`, a `Menu` as static elements and a a `Switch` which directs to the requested page.

A `selectedItem` `State` in `App` manages the chosen category of products/content/info/whatever the user is requesting and passes it to the component tree via `App`.

This `selectedItem`, when modified, is called in via a `setMenuItem` which is triggered when users clicks on a `MenuItem` from the `Menu`.

`selectedItem` `State` is sent back to `Menu` and `Header` for updating the `MenuItem` clicked and give it some style.

On click on a `MenuItem`, `useHistory` hook will trigger the `DisplayCategory` component, whose aim is to display the products/content/info/whatever selected from the `MenuItem`.

This `DisplayCategory` , once called via `history.push()` method, will get the category of products/content/info/whatever to display via the `history.location.state` and will fetch data from `Firebase/FireStore` database.

A `useEffect` is called to fill the main state from `DisplayCategory`, namely `categoryData`, with the info fetched using an `async` function and to insert `Category` sub-components in the DOM.

**The problem** is that `DisplayCategory` is loaded a lot of times and that it creates a very unpleasant blinking effect among all the content which is loaded 3 times.
As you see below in the console output, each time `DisplayCategory` is updated, **it loads first the previous content and then the new one.**

Here is the console output :

1. App
2. Header
3. menu
4. render MenuItem (x2) <== the previous menuItem is losing style and the current is gaining style
5. Display Category
6. Category (x times, it reloads the previous categories)
7. displayCategory
8. displayCategory
9. Category (x times, it loads the current categories)

Here is the `DisplayCategory` Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./firebase-config";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Category from "./category";

const DisplayCategory = (props) => {
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();
  const { category } = useParams();

  const getCategoryData = async () => {
    setCategoryData([]);
    const queryCategories = doc(db, "categoryItems", history.location.state);
    const data = await getDoc(queryCategories);
    const categoryList = [];
    for (const [entry, value] of Object.entries(data.data())) {
      categoryList.push(
        <Category
          category={history.location.state}
          key={entry + value.origin}
          origin={value.origin}
          entry={entry}
          name={value.name}
        >
          {value.name}
        </Category>
      );
    }
    setCategoryData(categoryList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategoryData();
    props.previousMenuItem.current !== history.location.state &&
      props.handleMenuItem(history.location.state);
    props.previousMenuItem.current = history.location.state;
  }, [history.location.state]);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="displayCategory" className="display">
        {props.selectedItem}
        <div>{props.previousMenuItem.current === category && categoryData}</div>
      </div>
      {console.log("Display Category")}
    </>
  );
};

export default DisplayCategory;
```

You can find a more detailed overview of the project here

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-liskov-l0nxjb

It's necessary that you replace the  `Firebase` credentials with one of yours though.

Anyone has an idea of what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a suspicion that your useEffect works out several times , which causes the flashing effect . the first time during initialization, the second when changing the variable that you specified in the useEffect dependencies.
Maybe you meant it .

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getCategoryData()
        if (props.previousMenuItem.current !== history.location.state && props.handleMenuItem(history.location.state)) {
            props.previousMenuItem.current = history.location.state
        }
    }, [history.location.state])
```

There are several simple ways to solve this problem :
1)

```
const WrapComponent = () => {
    const [dataFetch, setDataFetch] = useState(undefined)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setDataFetch({data: 'data'})
        }, 1000)
    }, [])

    //! it is important that the rendering conditions of the component comes after all the hooks
    if (!dataFetch) return null

    return (
        <div>
            <SomeComponent dataFetch={dataFetch}/>
        </div>
    )
}
const SomeComponent = ({dataFetch}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {dataFetch.data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

2. 

```
const WrapComponent = () => {
    const [dataFetch, setDataFetch] = useState(undefined)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setDataFetch({data: 'data'})
        }, 1000)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <SomeComponent dataFetch={dataFetch}/>
        </div>
    )
}

const SomeComponent = ({dataFetch}) => {

    if (!dataFetch) return null

    return (
        <div>
            {dataFetch.data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

3. 

```
const WrapComponent = () => {
    const [dataFetch, setDataFetch] = useState(undefined)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setDataFetch({data: 'data'})
        }, 1000)
    }, [])

    //! it is important that the rendering conditions of the component comes after all the hooks
    if (!dataFetch) return null

    return (
        <div>
            {dataFetch && <SomeComponent dataFetch={dataFetch}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
const SomeComponent = ({dataFetch}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {dataFetch.data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Depending on the task , choose the appropriate approach.

```
const WrapComponent = () => {
    const [dataFetch, setDataFetch] = useState({data: undefined, status: 'idle'})

    useEffect(() => {
        // request start
        setDataFetch({status: 'pending', data: 'data'})

        setTimeout(() => {
            //query result

            setDataFetch({status: 'fulfilled', data: 'data'})
            //or
            setDataFetch({status: 'rejected', data: 'data'})

        }, 1000)
    }, [])

    //! it is important that the rendering conditions of the component comes after all the hooks
    if (!dataFetch) return null

    return (
        <div>
            {dataFetch.status === 'fulfilled' && <SomeComponent dataFetch={dataFetch}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I use this option myself, but in a different form, using the redux-toolkit.

Comment: yes @MKinG exactly, in fact the async fetching is making the problem, this is why, but how to solve this ? like, preventing the component to render before the data has not loaded ?

Comment: @NataSh I have completed my answer